# Why do I get an error about being unable to change rasterizer states in this code?

Tags: xna, c#

I'm trying to toggle between wireframe and full mode while drawing a 3d model. So far I have this

```
 rs = new RasterizerState();
```

In my update method:

```
  if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.V))
        {
            rs.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
        }

        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.C))
        {
            rs.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
        }
```

and in my draw method:

```
  GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;
```

But I get the error:

```
 Cannot change read-only RasterizerState. State objects become read-only the first time they are bound to a GraphicsDevice. To change property values, create a new RasterizerState instance.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want a solid understanding of why things are they way they are and how best to interact with XNA's states takes a look at this blog post. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/02/state-objects-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting appears to explain both the problem and the solution:

> Cannot change read-only RasterizerState. State objects become
>   read-only the first time they are bound to a GraphicsDevice. To change
>   property values, create a new RasterizerState instance.

You can't change rasterizer state objects once you have bound them to a graphics device (which happens the first time you assign `rs` to `GraphicsDevice.RenderState`). Instead, create a new rasterizer state with your desired settings and assign that to the device.

Save the previous reference if you expect to ever want to reuse that old state (as you probably do, once you disable the wireframe mode).

Comment: Oh awesome. I should read the errors more carefully